# get naturalSize and list resolution video m3u8

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming

I play video m3u8.

I try use`let videoAssetSource = AVAsset(url: videoURL)` but `videoAssetSource.tracks(withMediaType: .video).count` always return 0.
When I use link mp4 this is successful.

How to get list quality link m3u8 support and change quality when playing video.

Comment: To change the quality apple only provides the preferredPeakBitRate https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388541-preferredpeakbitrate but if you are on adaptive hls there’s no way to get the list of available bit rates via AVFoundation, you must parse the m3u8

Answer (score 5):

You will have to create your own respective models for resolutions but then a code like this should work.

```objectivec
    /// Downloads the stream file and converts it to the raw playlist.
    /// - Parameter completion: In successful case should return the `RawPlalist` which contains the url with which was the request performed
    /// and the string representation of the downloaded file as `content: String` parameter.
    func getPlaylist(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<RawPlaylist, Error>) -> Void) {
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else if let data = data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                completion(.success(RawPlaylist(url: url, content: string)))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(PlayerException.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE)) // Probably an MP4 file.
            }
        }
        task?.resume()
    }

    /// Iterates over the provided playlist contetn and fetches all the stream info data under the `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF"` key.
    /// - Parameter playlist: Playlist object obtained from the stream url.
    /// - Returns: All available stream resolutions for respective bandwidth.
    func getStreamResolutions(from playlist: RawPlaylist) -> [StreamResolution] {
        var resolutions = [StreamResolution]()
        playlist.content.enumerateLines { line, shouldStop in
            let infoline = line.replacingOccurrences(of: "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF", with: "")
            let infoItems = infoline.components(separatedBy: ",")
            let bandwidthItem = infoItems.first(where: { $0.contains(":BANDWIDTH") })
            let resolutionItem = infoItems.first(where: { $0.contains("RESOLUTION")})
            if let bandwidth = bandwidthItem?.components(separatedBy: "=").last,
               let numericBandwidth = Double(bandwidth),
               let resolution = resolutionItem?.components(separatedBy: "=").last?.components(separatedBy: "x"),
               let strignWidth = resolution.first,
               let stringHeight = resolution.last,
               let width = Double(strignWidth),
               let height = Double(stringHeight) {
                resolutions.append(StreamResolution(maxBandwidth: numericBandwidth,
                                                    averageBandwidth: numericBandwidth,
                                                    resolution: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))
            }
        }
        return resolutions
    }
}
```

Comment: What is RawPlaylist, StreamResolution? Xcode can't find those items.

Comment: @SamiulIslamSami just my custom classes to where I map the obtained data. You can see the constructors of those object in the code snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe an observer to the property tracks on a player item:

```
//Define this variable globally
var observers:[NSKeyValueObservation]? = [NSKeyValueObservation]()

//Find tracks
let videoAssetSource = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoAssetSource)

let tracksObserver = self.playerItem.observe(\.tracks, options: [.old, .new]) { (item, change) in
     for track in item.tracks {
        let _assetTrack:AVAssetTrack? = track.assetTrack
        if let assetTrack = _assetTrack {
           if assetTrack.mediaType == .video {
              //we found a video track
           } 
        }
     }
}

//Keep observer reference
observers?.append(tracksObserver)
```

Im using Swift 4 block-based key value observer, but you can use the observeValue(forKeyPath:…) if you want.

Comment: hls/m3u8 returns an empty array for `tracks`